Why is WPS using N up printing?
What settings might have caused this?

I've tried many different ones like:

The printer prints well with other software so it's definitely an issue with WPS PDF. Please help me out. I suspect I misused some settings but I have no idea what.
Sorry for all the images. I did my very best to keep it all below 160 kb.

see this official wps video https://www.facebook.com/share/v/bQomvPGeSN82ZTGT/?mibextid=NXeFpL

Will do. Thanks!

I know the interface really well @TalaatEtman. I’ve been using this software for six years now. This particular issue started with the latest July update. You might setup the document the way you want but on printing… boom! It comes out like that. I’m not ruling out the fact that I might have done something though. Have you encountered this before?

try to delete the wps configuration files in your ~/.conf, my be a conflict occurred after the update, or try to create new test user to see if the problem still exists or not.

Instead of wasting paper, install the boomaga or PDF printer driver and test with them.

@FedKad it doesn't happen with other software so it is definitely WPS PDF related. I wanted to go with Talaat Etman's suggestion but I don't know how to get hold of WPS conf file. I've been searching but I couldn't find it.
